# How does the demoman charge?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-demoman

I've read some of the [demoman](http://tf2wiki.net/wiki/Demoman)'s weapon descriptions, and some of them affect "charge rates".

How do you do it?

I saw some players doing what I think was a charge (running fast to perform a melee attack), but I didn't see any indication about it when I play as demoman.

Comment: Figures, you ask an easy TF2 question right after I leave. :/

Comment: Don't worry, I may have more in the future. Also, feel free to add another answer with more info for some sweet sweet rep.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Chargin' Targe](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Chargin%27_Targe) is a shield for the Demoman, often used in combination with a sword to make a "DemoKnight". It starts with an initial charge, and upon right-clicking your mouse, the demoman will zoom forward, increasing their damage with the sword/pan/bottle (by making attacks crits / minicrits). You will often see them slicing the heads off of some people with plenty of blood once they stop moving. You need to be wearing the shield to use it. A charge bar will be in the bottom right corner.

The [Splendid Screen](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Splendid_Screen) is the other Demoman shield, which does more damage than the Chargin' Targe, but has fewer bonuses.

Recently, they added a third shield called [The Tide Turner](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Tide_Turner), which has the unique ability to fully recharge the charge meter if the player makes a kill on the charge.

Tactically, from my experience, it's a fun thing to do by charging into a crowd and chopping off a few limbs. Each takes 12 seconds for a new charge up.

Equipping the [Persian Persuader](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Persian_Persuader) melee weapon will grant the user 100% increase in recharge rate.

Comment: @AustinMohr Feel free to edit it to reflect any recent changes, this was as of the time, about 3 years ago